# How do you create a bounding box that a sprite cannot pass through?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, bounding-box

This is the form of collision detection that i am using it is not allowing the player to pass but when it collide with the tile it preforms two of the if statements at once.

```
  if (_mainCharac->position->X < (_mainCrate->posRect->X + _mainCrate->sourceRect->Width) && 
    (_mainCharac->position->X + _mainCharac->sourceRect->Width) > _mainCrate->posRect->X && 
    _mainCharac->position->Y < (_mainCrate->posRect->Y + _mainCrate->sourceRect->Height) &&
    _mainCharac->sourceRect->Height + _mainCharac->position->Y > _mainCrate->posRect->Y)
{
    if (_mainCharac->position->X > _mainCrate->posRect->X)
        _mainCharac->position->X = _mainCharac->position->X + 2;//Right

    if (_mainCharac->position->Y < _mainCrate->posRect->Y)
        _mainCharac->position->Y = _mainCharac->position->Y - 2;//Top

    if (_mainCharac->position->X < _mainCrate->posRect->X)
        _mainCharac->position->X = _mainCharac->position->X - 2;//Left

    if (_mainCharac->position->Y > _mainCrate->posRect->Y)
        _mainCharac->position->Y = _mainCharac->position->Y + 2;//Bottom
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your detection is fine, but I would do adjustment something like this:

```
 if (_mainCharac->position->X > _mainCrate->posRect->X + _mainCrate->sourceRect->Width/2)
      _mainCharac->position->X = _mainCharac->position->X + 2;//Right
 else
      _mainCharac->position->X = _mainCharac->position->X - 2;//Left

 if (_mainCharac->position->Y < _mainCrate->posRect->Y + _mainCrate->sourceRect->Height/2)
      _mainCharac->position->Y = _mainCharac->position->Y - 2;//Top
 else
      _mainCharac->position->Y = _mainCharac->position->Y + 2;//Bottom
```